# Can't save img url in TinyMCE when it's rotated due to adding base64 data?

Tags: mysql, sql, tinymce

So I've been using TinyMCE for a while now in order to let users add images to pages, and they basically just drag the image into the editor and save it.

HOwever I've just realized a bug. If they put the image in the editor and rotate it, it won't save.

WHen I save an image without rotating it saves the HTML with the image source like 'img_2012.jpg' but when it's rotated it looks more like 'src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeAAAAKACA.....' and on and on

So it looks like rotating it creates some kind of base64 encoding that won't allow it to save as content in the database.

Is there a reason for this?

```
$addContent = "
    INSERT INTO htmlCont.content(content)
    VALUES('$content');
";

if ($mysqlConn->query($addContent) === TRUE) {
    $cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;
    $data['last_insert_id'] = $cont_id;
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $addContent . "<br>" . $mysqlConn->error;
}
```

The data being inserted here is in html format and is coming from an ajax data object

Comment: is there a SQL/PHP error? What is the PHP code?

Comment: Yes I just added it, sorry. So the content being saved is always html format, and usually saves when it's just <img src="image.jpg"> but this error comes with all the base64 garbage

Comment: @danblack it says data too long for column 'content'

Comment: its not garbage, its the representation for the image. What SQL type is content (`SHOW CREATE TABLE htmlCont.content`)? Fixing SQL injection will solve your next problem too.

Comment: It's type of text right now

Comment: there's a longtext type - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html. You can't control a lot what the browser gives you.